# C# - storing multiple values in a string

Tags: c#

I'm newbie in C# so please go easy on me... basically, I'm reading through a text file and want to grab any data between two strings and store all of this data into a string / variable - how would I go about doing this?

I've already got the below but just need a push in the right direction to get me back on track.

Many Thanks

**C# Code:**

```
bool DetailsFound = false;
string[] ReadLines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
foreach (string item in ReadLines) {
    if (item == "Start Details") {
        DetailsFound = true;
    }
    if (DetailsFound) {
        Console.WriteLine("Details - " + item);
        // VARIABLE / STRING REQUIRED HERE
    }
    if (item == "End Details") {
        break;
    }
}
```

**Example *.TXT File**

```
Start Details
I am line 1
I am line 2
I am line 3
End Details
```

Comment: You should use lower camel case for variable names; so detailsFound rather than DetailsFound

Comment: So would your expected output be the contents of the file minus the `Start Details` and `End Details` lines?

Comment: Looks like a job for `List<String>`.

Comment: Declare `string strAllLine = string.Empty;` then in if loop `if (DetailsFound) {
        Console.WriteLine("Details - " + item);
        strAllLine = strAllLine + item;
    }` so all the Line value will be stored in strAllLine string.

Comment: @user3501749 Don't do that.

Comment: @user3501749 Oh boy. We have ourselves a [Shlemiel the Painter](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/) here.

Comment: 7 answer? Man they duplicate really quickly, Is it midnight where you are? Are your feeding the grimlins? Whats the next step? 7 answer using `using`?

Comment: Is it the only thing you have to do on those lines? Wouldn't regex similar to this: `(?<=Start Details\n)(.*)(?=End Details)`, with single-line option, work?; @DragandDrop, here, a regex one ;)

Comment: @Mars, you wan't to submit it? For the sake of diversity you should!

Comment: @DragandDrop Indeed, the first two answers that came in were different in their approach. The others just replicate the first two and came in 4 minutes after the first two. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48422595/timeline

Comment: @DragandDrop, the OP seems to be not experienced and I have not enough data to claim "this is a good answer to your question", thus I will not add it. Let it stay here as "ah, there might be other way", in case OP or other peer wonder.

Comment: It's ok. Every one wants to help. I know, I was my self writing an answer. I didn't said any one copy past or even investigate at timestamp. I was just surprice I Had to hit refresh every minute for 7-8 minutes because an answer or an edit were comming out. When a post reach 8 answer no up vote with ~30 view, it got me thinking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do everything in the correct order.
Use something like [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) to store the strings.

```
var detailsFound = false;
var readLines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
var stringB = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string item in readLines) {
    if (item == "Start Details") {
        detailsFound = true;
    }
    else if (item == "End Details") {
        break;
    }
    else if (detailsFound) {
        Console.WriteLine("Details - " + item);
        stringB.AppendLine(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to fix your logic to handle the end correctly (it's a matter of execution order).

Then, use a `StringBuilder` to concatenate the strings:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (string item in ReadLines) {
    if (item == "Start Details") {
        DetailsFound = true;
    }
    else if (item == "End Details") {
        break;
    }
    else if (DetailsFound) {
        Console.WriteLine("Details - " + item);
        sb.AppendLine(item);
        // VARIABLE / STRING REQUIRED HERE
    }
}

string output = sb.ToString();
```

If you want to have the lines a separate values, use a `List<string>`:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();

foreach (string item in ReadLines) {
    if (item == "Start Details") {
        DetailsFound = true;
    }
    else if (item == "End Details") {
        break;
    }
    else if (DetailsFound) {
        Console.WriteLine("Details - " + item);
        list.Add(item);
        // VARIABLE / STRING REQUIRED HERE
    }
}

// list holds all lines
```

Answer (score 1):

Few comments:

- You should look at MSDN for [General Naming Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions)
- Using `File.ReadAllLines` will load all the lines in the file to memory. In this instance, I don't think we want to do it as we may stop after several lines. Consider using [`File.ReadLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx)

You were given plenty of answers that use the usual enumeration, which is great for a C# beginner as it should look familiar to other languages. I want to expose you to one powerful C# feature, [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/getting-started-with-linq).

You can perform the task in the following manner:

```
    public static void TakeBetween(string filePath, string startText, string endText)
    {
        var data = File.ReadLines(filePath).SkipWhile(line => !line.Contains(startText)).Skip(1).TakeWhile(line => !line.Contains(endText));
        // Do whatever that is needed with data. It is of type IEnumerable<string>
    }
```

you can replace `.Contains` with any other string finding method you desire. Note that this won't load unnecessary data to memory.

Relevant LINQ functions:

- [SkipWhile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549075(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Skip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [TakeWhile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534804(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks Eylon - I will take a read through the links you provided.

Answer (score 0):

You're not too far off.

With a few minor modifications to your code:

```
List<string> results = new List<string>();

foreach (string item in ReadLines) 
{
    if (item == "Start Details") 
    {
        DetailsFound = true;
    }
    else if (item == "End Details") {
        break;
    }
    else if (DetailsFound) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Details - " + item);
        results.Add(item);
    }

}
```

That will store the strings found in a list. Now you can process them as you wish. For instance, you can get them all together in a single comma-separated string:

```
var commaSeparated = String.Join(results, ", ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;


namespace Oppgave3Lesson1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "";
            List<string> lines = new List<string>();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);

            Boolean foundStart = false;
            while ((input = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (!foundStart)
                {
                    if(input.StartsWith("Start")) foundStart = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (input.StartsWith("End")) break;
                    lines.Add(input);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to output the lines after some specific string, I'd do it like this

```
const string _startIdentifier = "Start Details"
const string _endIdentifier = "End Details"

private bool detailsFound
private List<string> details

foreach (string item in File.ReadAllLines(path)) {
    if (!detailsFound && item.Equals(_startIdentifier) {
        detailsFound = true;
    }

    if (item.Equals(__endIdentifier){
        break;
    }

    if (detailsFound) {
        details.Add(item);
        Console.WriteLine("Details - " + item);
    }
}
```

Then if you want to combine those items into a single string

```
var combinedItems = String.Join(", ", items)
```

That will create a string that looks something like "I am line 1, I am line 2, I am line 3". Of course you can change the deliminator from a comma to a new line with `Environment.NewLine`

Comment: Edited my answer @PatrickHofman. Not sure if by 'store' the OP means in memory (as a list like I'm using) or as a single string (in which case Sani's string builder solution is probably better)

Answer (score 0):

item is defined in the foreach loop and refers to the read line.
You must define before the loop a string variable and attach each item.

```
string WriteDataHere = String.Empty; // <- 

bool DetailsFound = false;
string[] ReadLines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
foreach (string item in ReadLines) {
    if (item == "Start Details") {
    DetailsFound = true;
}
if (DetailsFound) {
    Console.WriteLine("Details - " + item);
    // VARIABLE / STRING REQUIRED HERE
    WriteDataHere += item; // <--
    }
    if (item == "End Details") {
        break;
    }
}
```

But this solution would cause a string that looks like this:

> I am line 1I am line 2I am line 3

A possible solution is to check if this string is empty and add a linebreak if notso the code line looks a little bit different:

```
if( String.isNullOrEmpty(WriteDataHere) == false)
   WriteDataHere += "\n";

WriteDataHere += item; // <--
```

A little bit better solution is to save all "items" in a List

```
List<string> listOfStrings = new List<string>();
```

and add each item on each iteration via the Add-Method.

But it depends on what you plan to do with your string.

Comment: Never use string concatenation in a tight loop.

Comment: Can you explain why I never should use it and what a tight loop is? I'm interested in the background of this statement.